# the content of pointer changed when passed to the function

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am using C++ to do my work. The following is the problem I am confulsed.

```
typedef struct netHandler {
    int m_iFd;
    poll_event_t* m_pPollEvent;
    epoll_event m_Event;
    void* m_pConn;
} netHandler_t;
```

Here is my struct. When the program running. I set a breakpoint in the following place:

```
connection_t* conn = geneConnection(idenfication, fd, handler);
```

And before step into this funcition, I record the handler's content.

```
p *(netHandler_t *) 0x2aaaac000960
$2 = {m_iFd = 9, m_pPollEvent = 0x2aaaac000930, m_Event = 
    {events = 1, data = {ptr =    0x2aaaac000960, fd = -1409283744, u32 = 2885683552, u64 = 46912518490464}}, 
    m_pConn = 0x60d010}
```

Then I step into the geneConnection function. The content changed.

```
p *(netHandler_t *) 0x2aaaac000960
$3 = {m_iFd = 9, m_pPollEvent = 0xac00093000000000, m_Event = 
    {events = 10922, data = {ptr = 0xac00096000000001, fd = 1, u32 = 1, u64 = 12393916482445115393}}, 
    m_pConn = 0x2aaa}
```

That's like the struct was shrifted.

```
connection_t* geneConnection(long iden, int sendfd, netHandler_t* handler);
```

This is the declare of geneConnection. I don't understand why this happened. When I change this function to inline type. The content of handler would not changed.

Comment: `epoll_event.data` looks like a union

Comment: try doing a clean and rebuild on your whole project, make sure every unit is using the same compiler options . Is everything in the same project or are you stepping into a dll or static library?

Comment: A [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very useful.

Comment: Where does `handler` come from? Is it a local variable of a function that has already returned?

Comment: Looks rather like you had structure packing set differently when you compiled the caller than when you compiled the `geneConnection` function. Like one of the header files does a `#pragma pack` and then doesn't reset it.